# are all C# statements atomic?

Tags: c#

Consider the below statements

```
Stock.Price = Trade.HasPrice ? Trade.Price : 0;
```

Does the framework guarantee that above statement gets executed atomically?
How about multi-line LINQ statments?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "statements".  The properties themselves could internally have a considerable amount of logic which wouldn't reasonably be atomic.

Comment: This isn't a statement (something that doesn't return a value), it's multiple expressions. `Price`, `HasPrice` may be fields, or properties, with simple getters, or getters that perform a lot of work

Comment: Either can be a property which are hell-no-atomic. Do you have an issue with multithreading or what is the reasons behind the question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's multiple expressions that make up a statement.  Yes, it *is* a statement.

Comment: This is not atomic. "multi-line LINQ statements" are definitly not atomic. They are several method calls, using _iterator blocks_ and deferred execution. afaik only simple assignments (like references or values smaller than or equal to 64bit) are atomic (but I'd have to read the specs again for a correct answer).

Comment: @Hunter I think he is asking if this statement is threadsafe and the answer is no because it's just compiled to if else statement

Comment: @Hunter do you know what the statement translates to..? it's like an inline IfElse,

Comment: @Servy if we have to get pedantic, no it's an assigment expression that returns the assigned value. That's not the OP's question though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't say it wasn't an expression.  The OP said it was a statement, you said that it wasn't, and I said that, no, it is a statement.  It *is* a statement.  It's *also* an expression, and it's *also* a combination of component expressions, but that doesn't mean it's *not* a statement.

Comment: It's almost as though a statement is composed of one or more expressions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the discussion. So atomicity is determined by the processor. so a 32 bit processor can execute instruction where the values are of 32 bit max. Where as thread safety is different where we can have synchronization blocks to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

> Does the framework guarantee that above statement gets executed atomically? How about multi-line LINQ statements?

The answer is "no" for both questions. If the state of `Trade` changes in between of obtaining `HasPrice` and retrieving the price, you may get an exception.

If you would like to retrieve the price atomically, you need to design your API for that. For example, you could structure the retrieval method as follows:

```
decimal price;
if (Trade.TryGetPrice(out price)) {
    Stock.Price = price;
}
```

`TryGetPrice` returns `true` if the price is available, and `false` otherwise.

Now it is up to your `TryGetPrice` implementation to stay atomic. As long as it does, the operation described above is going to work correctly.

Comment: Note that your proposed change is still not at all atomic as a single operation (even assuming `TryGetPrice` is logically atomic).

Comment: @Servy My understanding of OP's concern is that he wants a guarantee that if `HasPrice` returned `true`, then `Trade.Price` must return a valid price. That is the concern I am trying to address with restructuring the API.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not get executed atomically.  In fact, the *vast* majority of statements aren't guaranteed to be atomic.  Of course, there are lots of statements where there's no practical means of observing the fact that it's no atomic (basically any operation that has no side effects, and is not observing any value that could be mutated) but that doesn't mean that such an operation is *actually* atomic (even though you can conceptually *treat* it as though it's atomic).

As far as the specific example you shown, here's an incomplete, and unordered list of times during this operation that another operation might happen (whether or not such other operations can cause observable side effects):

- after `Trade` is resolved to a value and before `HasPrice` is resolved to a value
- after `HasPrice` is resolved to a value
- after the branch is performed to determine the path of the conditional statement
- after `Trade` is resolved to a value a second time (if that path is taken)
- after `Price` is resolved to a value
- after the conditional is resolved to a value
- after `Stock` is resolved to a value
- after `Price` is resolved to a variable, but before the actual assignment

All of those points run after some operation has been performed but before the entire operation has finished, making the operation not atomic.